# Why does logic of iff(null, , ) depend on type of the operands?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

```
print iff(1.0 > real(null), 1.0, -1.0), iff(1.0 > real(null), true, false)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-1    |   <null>
```

Though I did not find it documented, since the logic of *where* [treats *null* as *false*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/null-values?pivots=azuredataexplorer#null-values-and-the-where-query-operator), it is logical that `iff()` goes to *ifFalse* expression. However, I find it strange that with boolean *if*-expressions it evaluates to null.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This will be fixed in future versions.

Comment: Fixed and started traversing through the various deployment cycles. You should expect to see the change within a few weeks.